# Swift 4 Why Delegate is not working

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

In ViewController :

```
protocol SearchResultDelegate {
    func SendDataToResultController(_ result: [SkelbimasModel])
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate, AddSkelbimas {

    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var SearchBar: UISearchBar!
    // @IBOutlet weak var boomFilter: BoomMenuButton!
   // @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var CategoryView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Map: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bmb: BoomMenuButton!

    var Delegate:SearchResultDelegate?
.........

     //ijungimiame lentele su paieskos rezultatais
            if(result.count > 1) {
                Delegate?.SendDataToResultController(result)
                GoToSearchResultVC(result)

            }
```

Function GoToSearchResultVC(result) is called it opens new controller
in that new controller code is :

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultTableViewController: UITableViewController, SearchResultDelegate {
.....

func SendDataToResultController(_ result: [SkelbimasModel]) {
    print("result count: \(result.count)")
    results = result
}
```

But this function is never called. 
I used delegates before and was fine. Or i'm just tired and do not see where i did wrong...

Comment: Maybe assign delegate to self somewhere? In view did load for example. 

Not sure how are you passing the delegate between view controllers.

Comment: First check delegate is nil?

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere where you create the `ViewController` in your code in `SearchResultTableViewController` you have to set the value of the delegate:

```
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.Delegate = self
// present viewController
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing after SearchResultTableViewController from ViewController, isn't it easier to do something like:

```
func GoToSearchResultVC(result: Any) {
    let searchVC = SearchResultTableViewController()
    searchVC.results = results
    self.present(searchVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Delegate design patter is to receive events from other classes, if you only want to set a variable, this way is better for me

BTW checking your code, you are calling first the delegate before creating the SearchResultsVC